# for-await-in loop not working in Swift 5.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, asynchronous, async-await

I was reading the Concurrency section in the Swift 5.5 documentation (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Concurrency.html#ID640) and copy pasted this example code in a MacOS command line project:

```
import Foundation

func someFunction() async throws {
    let handle = FileHandle.standardInput       // Directly from example
    for try await line in handle.bytes.lines {  // Directly from example
        print(line)                             // Directly from example
    }                                           // Directly from example
}
```

When I built this I got the following errors:

- await must precede try *(This is weird considering in the documentation `await` comes after `try`)*
- Expected '{' to start the body of for-each loop
- Expected pattern
- Value of type 'FileHandle' has no member 'bytes'

I literally copy pasted the code so I shouldn't be getting any such errors. I am using MacOS 11.4 and Xcode version 12.5.1. I downloaded the latest toolchain for Swift 5.5 which was released July 1st, 2021. All the previous code with `async` and `await` is working for me. Any idea why this is happening?

### Things I've tried so far that have not worked:

- Making the function return `Void` as suggested by Ayrton
- Tried adding `if #available(macOS 12.0, *)` in the function body
- I tried extending `FileHandle` to add conformance to `AsyncSequence`: 
  `extension FileHandle: AsyncSequence { }`
  It said that `FileHandle` doesn't conform to `AnySequence`.

Comment: FYI this works fine in Xcode 13 beta (assuming the target is macOS 12.0), which has native support for the Swift 5.5 toolchain.

Comment: Are you running macOS 12.0? `async-await` is only available on the new version of the Apple platforms that are currently in beta. So if you're running macOS 11, you won't be able to use these.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm running MacOS 11.4. When I tested other code using `async-await` it built perfectly fine without any errors.